# username availability security concerns

Tags: php, ajax, security

In a registration form I have, I put an ajax call to check if the username is available.

However, I am concerned that this opens up the system for a bot checking for valid usernames.

How can I secure the service from external calls?

Thanks

Comment: If your site is secure from a bot registering, I wouldn't really lose sleep over some arbitrary script checking which usernames have been taken.

Answer (score 5):

> How can I secure the service from external calls?

Well... ANY user trying to register would be an "external call"!

I don't see how username checking would be a security risk. A bot could just register as `fsdjiojiejfio` and be pretty darn sure nobody took that before.

I would rather invest time into securing the registration process so that bots cannot register, even with a valid username.

Comment: Agree. Just make this call fast enough so it doesn't become a performance botlleneck and you'll be fine.

Comment: @cherouvim: the key is probably to take time - as in seconds - responding to a request where the username is already taken.  This means that if a bot is trying, it can only try slowly on each connection.  The response time needs to be slow enough that it seriously limits a computer while fast enough not to irritate the genuine user.  Somewhere in the 1-5 second range is likely appropriate.

Comment: Guys thanks for the help. Jonathan, how can you distinquish a bot from a user? If a user registering checks for a username that is taken and I respod after 3 secs, it is a bit annoying. Imagine him trying 5 times

Comment: @Thomas: what you can do is to put a CAPTCHA, and send an email to the user. That will stop the great majority of bots. I agree that 3 sec is a bit long, but 1 would do.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: How can you (on purpose) make a web based response slow? I've tried it and it's not very safe. A slow response will most probably occupy a finite resource (thread, database connection) which will make it a good candidate for a DoS attack.

Comment: @cherouvim: I don't have enough experience with web sites to answer your question. There are computationally expensive ways to do it (like hash the password a few hundred times even though you're going to tell them that the user ID is NBG), but you probably want the system doing useful work while the user waits for the response. Yes, you clearly run the risk of a multi-threaded or multi-bot DOS attack. You have to balance risks. Taking time to tell the potential new user that the chosen name is already in use gives you protection from one mode of attack, but opens another mode of attack. Ouch!

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: A general rule for webapps is to try and get the response out as quickly as possible. Otherwise you will experience availability issues when the amount of requests arriving is greater than the amount of responses you can serve. Buffers will at some point get full and requests will be droped. So even for this use case ("does username exist?") I think he should reply as fast as possible and probably use some sort of bot-detecting patterns for not replying at all.

Comment: @cherouvim: those requirements are someone antithetical to security requirements - as I said, you have to balance risks.

Comment: @cherouvim: you can reply as soon as possible but query only every second.

Answer (score 1):

I presume your concern is that allowing "is this username available?" checks would allow someone with nefarious intent to only have to guess a password to log in, rather than having to guess a username as well.  I think that's a valid concern, though I'm not sure I would worry myself overly about it.

The only secure way around this issue, I think, would be to require a captcha before you get to the registration page.

Comment: AND send an email with an activation link.

Comment: @nico If your concern is registering accounts, yes. If it's getting usernames to try to brute-force an existing login, then that wouldn't help.

Comment: @lonesomeday: I'm pretty sure the OP wants to have user registering to his website...

Comment: @nico Yes, but the general concern for finding out usernames would be for logging in. I'm not sure what the OP's concern is, but I personally would be more concerned about the login issue.

Comment: @lonesomeday: I'm pretty sure there are much easier ways to know the names of the users on a website. Say... if it's a forum look at the nicknames of the people who write there, or lots of sites have a user list and so on. I would not really be concerned about this problem, as long as the rest of the site's backend is secure.

Comment: My concern is the one that lonesomeday states

Comment: @Thomas, say you want to know the usernames on stackoverflow. Why would you go into all the trouble of calling the name-checking routine (that does not exist on SO, but that's not the point), just look at the homepage and you'll get all the names you want.

Comment: @nico But that isn't true for all websites...  Lots of websites will display a "real name" rather than a username, for instance, and lots will show nothing at all.

Comment: @lonesomeday: sure, but say you found that the user `john` exists. Now what? You still have to hack the password, which is the part where you need to secure your website. Finding usernames is definitely not a security concern.

Comment: @nico Definitely not a big security concern, correct. I agree fully.